# Networkx doesn't parse all the network edges from file

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have a file with 3 columns. The first and second column show the edges and the third column is the sign(weight) of the edge. The file has 450 lines, so i thought that i must have 450 edges.
Im parsing the edges with networkx with the following code:

```
G = nx.read_edgelist('myfile.txt', delimiter='\t', nodetype=int, data=(('sign', int),))
```

and the i print the number of graph edges with the following code:

```
n1 = nx.number_of_nodes(G)
n2 = nx.number_of_edges(G)
print("nodes: ", n1)
print("edges: ", n2)
```

and the result is less edges than 450. Why im getting this result? Is there any problem with parsing?

Comment: Maybe use the method of bisection to find the first aberrant row.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to be certain because you don't provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but I think the most likely explanation is that the same edge is added twice (perhaps with the node order switched).

By default networkx uses an undirected graph.  So a `u`-`v` edge and a `v`-`u` edge are the same thing.  If you try to add an already existing edge, it simply does nothing. Similarly edges from a node to itself are not allowed.  To use some other graph type, you need to set the `create_using` option for `read_edgelist`.